# Compare image with opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, flann

I'm trying find difference in two image

db_image:

[image: db_image]

query_image:

[image: query_image]

abs_diff:

[image: abs_diff]

query_image is greater than db_image a little bit. I'm using opencv SIFT to extract feature and FlannBasedMatcher to find Homography finaly i'm using absdiff to extract difference area . It's work ! But some image not warpPerspective prefect and have some anti-aliased noise pixel i think. how to solve this.
Sorry for my bad english!

Here is my source code :

```
grayscale_db = cv2.cvtColor(db_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_scale_query = cv2.cvtColor(query_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(grayscale_db, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(gray_scale_query, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
good = [m for m, n in matches if m.distance < 0.9 * n.distance]
result_area = None
h, w = grayscale_db.shape
if len(good) > threshold:
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    if return_area:
        return cv2.minAreaRect(dst_pts)

    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(dst_pts, src_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    result_area = cv2.warpPerspective(query_img, M, (w, h), borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
                                      borderValue=(255, 255, 255), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    diff = cv2.absdiff( db_img,result_area)
```

Comment: You probably also need to match the colors. The difference here seems more related to a change in color than anything else.